# Div goes to new line

Tags: html, css

Here is the site: http://magicdynamic.com/zoom2/

With Firefox the right empty div (#bookingForm and with it also its container #rightColumn) goes always on a new line, while with Google Chrome it goes to a newline only when you zoom.

What i want to do it's obviously avoid it from going to newline.

I tried in order to fix it:

- Put  both (rightColumn and leftColumn) as float left
- Put both as float left + width dimensions in pixel
- Position relative and left

but i couldnt solve the problem.

Can anyone help me out?

And another little question, how can i make my midColumn recognize the whole height of the page without specifying it? (i need it for the background)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after `<div id="topMenu"></div>`

Also it is good css code style when you place header and topmenu in a container, then leftcolumn and rightcolumn in another container and footer in another container. Because the rightcolumn and leftcolumn float left so you need another `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` to separate them from the footer.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple things you'll want to change. Remove `float: left` from `#footerZone` and add `clear: both`. To make it so your midColumn recognizes the full height of the page, simply add `overflow: hidden`.

You should read up on [clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html), since both of your problems stem from this CSS error.